# Ninject MVC 3 - Injecting dependencies into models and controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject, factory-pattern

I don't fully understand what's happening behind the scenes when we inject dependencies into controllers and models.

I have the following controller:

```
    public class TypeController : CommonController
    {
        private ILookUpService lookUpService;

        public TypeController(ILookUpService lookUpService)
        {
            this.lookUpService = lookUpService;    
        }   

    }
```

As the application starts, the lookup service is already available. So I guess that somewhere behind scenes we have code on the lines of

```
TypeController controller = new TypeController(service);
```

or something to do with factory (which I need to read up about).

When it comes to injecting a service into a view model, it doesn't work as I need to invoke an empty constructor without passing interface to my service.

So what is happening behind the scenes? How do I inject a service into a view model? I guess I'm missing some real fundamental stuff which is stopping me from doing what I need.

I have included FactoryPattern in the tags as my gut feeling tell me it has something to do with my problem..

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't inject anything into the view model. The view model should be a simple data container which is filled from the controller and therefore shouldn't have any dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not entirely sure whether this is right or wrong. I have slightly more complex mapping which I'm not going to handle with Automapper. Mapping requires some serialization/deserialization to/from the view/domain models. Currently this logic resides in a controller and it's a mess - there is too much code.

Comment: My main problem at the moment is that I can't inject anything into my view model. Once I can inject a service, I'll refactor a code and see whether this is an improvement of what I currently have. Even if it's wrong, I need to see it for myself and understand how I can improve this.

Comment: Instead of moving code from the controller to the view model you should move the code to services injected to the controller in this case.

Comment: This means that a service will be dependant on a view model, doesn't it?

Comment: No. In the end noramlly it is the controller which assigns the values to the model. The services are there to keep the controller simple and help it to get, convert or calculate the required data. Of course you can pass the model to a service using a method if there is a good reason for it and have it assign some or several values. e.g. auto mapping.